# Pyspark dataframe drop columns issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to drop two columns from a dataframe but I am facing an error as

```
**Error:**
drop() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

***Code:***
 excl_columns= row['exclude_columns'].split(',')
 df=df.drop(*excl_columns)

#print(excl_columns)
#['year_of_birth', 'ethnicity']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way which should work:

```
excl_columns = row['exclude_columns'].split(',')
df.select([c for c in df.columns if c not in excl_columns])
```

Comment: I am using a spark dataframe so I am getting an error message as "drop() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'"